# jQuery popup with faded background conflicts with transparent PNGs

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I'm building a popup shopping cart in a webshop, which acts like a kind of lightbox. The cart pops up when it should, and the background fades to gray when it should.

**Problem:** some elements in the page light up when fading, this is very ugly.

I'm using jQuery.fadeIn and jQuery.fadeOut.

My problem is demonstrated [here](http://tafereel.meyerdevelopment.nl/servies.html).

Click on the phrase "Shopping Bag" in the top right corner to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to fade the background separately, not rely on it inheriting the opacity from the containing element. Do you understand what I mean? You would have to perform two `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` in parallel.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the popup-cart-container show at all times and its children (popup-cart and popup-cart-background) be hidden and faded them both in and out instead of the popup-cart-container. Somehow that did the trick!

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it. Thanks for coming back to report and accept!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go my friend

```
.popup-cart-container {
display: none;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: 1000;
}
```